# Full width navbar logo Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a full length navbar logo with links under it which are justified to the right like so:

[image]

If possible, I want the rainbow lines to extend left and right and the actual logo to be somewhat centered/fixed. However I really suck at CSS (I can't even resize correctly), and it comes out not full length and covers the rest of the page like this:

[image]

_Layout:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-brand">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Site.css:

```
.navbar-brand {
    height: 120px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px; /* firefox bug fix */
    background-image: url('Site/Header_FeinTune-logo-banner.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You can try with this starter I made: http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/PzpMWB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Please write navbar-brand like this inside of navbar-header
<div class="container-fluid">   
 <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" > </a>` has to be above the navbar-header

Answer (score 1):

Try using container-fluid instead of container. That will set a full screen width.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  ...
```